# Tab selection using jQuery in MVC

Tags: jquery

I have four tabs set in my view as follows

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="#tabs-1">Case Summary</a></li>
    <li><a id="#tabs-2">Patient</a></li>
    <li><a id="#tabs-3">Physician</a></li>
    <li><a id="#tabs-4">Site</a></li>
    <li><a id="#tabs-5">Journal</a></li>
</ul>
```

What i need to do is, be able to have focus on the tag my controller action requires say by sending viewdata("TabSelected") = "tabs-3" for Physician info

Comment: I modified the tabs by removing the a tag, because it would not let me send with links

Answer (score 2):

This is much simpler if you're using jQuery UI tabs. jQuery UI is a fully supported set of widgets for creating an UI on the client side. One of the widgets provided is a tab widget.

Assuming you're using this, you can do something as simple as this:

On the controller action:

```
ViewData("SelectedTabIndex") = 1;
```

On the client side, in $(document).ready:

```
$('#myTabs').tabs({ selected: <%= ViewData["SelectedTabIndex"] %> });
```

Answer (score 0):

After putting the tabselected in the viewdata like so:

```
ViewData("TabSelected") = "tabs-3"
```

Simply put the following in your $(document).ready() function:

```
$('#<%=ViewData("TabSelected")%>').focus()
```

That should do it.